# JSON object - which structure makes more sense?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm just learning JSON & Javascript objects and trying to figure out the best way to structure an object for a particular project.

I think I've mapped out the object pretty well, but I've thought of two different ways of doing it and I'm not sure which is 'better' and what the implications are of doing it one way rather than the other.

```
    {
    "session": {
        "sessionId": "",
        "sessionTitle": "",
        "sessionDescription": "",
        "clientName": "",
        "sessionTopics": [{
            "topicNames": [
                "name of first topic",
                "name of second topic",
                "name of third topic",
                "name of fourth topic",
                "name of fifth topic"
            ],
            "topicChoices": [
                ["a", "c", "a", "b", "e", "a", "d", "e", "c", "b"],
                ["c", "b", "a", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b"],
                ["a", "b", "a", "b", "e", "a", "d", "e", "c", "d"],
                ["a", "c", "a", "b", "e", "a", "d", "e", "c", "b"],
                ["c", "d", "b", "c", "e", "b", "d", "e", "c", "a"]
            ],
            "topicLmode": [
                7, 9, 6, 9, 5
            ]
        }],
        "imageDescriptions": [
            "client's description of image A",
            "client's description of image B",
            "client's description of image C",
            "client's description of image D",
            "client's description of image E"
        ]
    }
}
```

-- or --

```
{
    "session": {
        "sessionId": "",
        "sessionTitle": "",
        "sessionDescription": "",
        "clientName": "",
        "sessionTopics": [{
            "firstTopic": [{
                "topicName": "name of first topic",
                "topicChoices": [
                    "b", "c", "a", "d", "e", "a", "e", "b", "c", "b"
                ],
                "lmodeRating" : 7
            }]
        }, {
            "secondTopic": [{
                "topicName": "second topic name",
                "topicChoices": [
                    "a", "c", "a", "b", "e", "a", "d", "e", "c", "b"
                ],
                "lmodeRating": 9
            }]
            }, {
            "thirdTopic": [{
                "topicName": "third topic name",
                "topicChoices": [
                    "a", "c", "a", "b", "e", "a", "d", "e", "c", "b"
                ],
                "lmodeRating": 6
            }]
            }, {
            "fourthTopic": [{
                "topicName": "fourth topic name",
                "topicChoices": [
                    "a", "c", "a", "b", "e", "a", "d", "e", "c", "b"
                ],
                "lmodeRating": 9
            }]
            }, {
            "fifthTopic": [{
                "topicName": "fifth topic name",
                "topicChoices": [
                    "a", "c", "a", "b", "e", "a", "d", "e", "c", "b"
                ],
                "lmodeRating": 5
            }]
        }],
        "imageDescriptions": [
        {
            "imageA": "description of image A"
        }, {
            "imageB": "description of image B"
        }, {
            "imageC": "description of image C"
        }, {
            "imageD": "description of image D"
        }, {
            "imageE": "description of image E"
        }
        ],
    }
}
```

I don't know whether it makes a difference to which would be better, but I won't know ahead of time how many "topics" there will be in each session (I do know it will be likely always be 4-6 topics).

Also possibly relevant -- I'll need to be able to get data by topic for some calculations and for output, as well as calculations across topics (e.g., comparing 'topicChoices' across two topics - is 4th choice the same in topic 1 as in topic 4?).

My gut tells me that perhaps that makes the first approach better (easier to work with), but I'm not sure.

I'm open to suggestions!

Thanks
Scott

Comment: the second one, easy to modify. Reorder and access. as well if you gonna pass info to submodules is more practical.

Comment: This is a topic for codereview rather than here

Comment: Its an object call. It  depends on your implementation. But in my understanding, I'll go with second approach

Comment: You have to think how you would parse the information in code. On the first structure, you would need to be guaranteed a matching set of values in another node. On the second example, you have all the values encapsulated together. Makes more sense and the data can be parsed as a unit.

Comment: This is primarily opinion based, even so option 2 is the clear winner.

Comment: It's not clear to me how `{ "thirdTopic": [{ ... }] }` is superior to simply `{ ... }`, since you don't appear to use the array to give `{...}` any siblings, and the `firstTopic`, `secondTopic`, etc. only add redundant info that is already encoded by the object's position in the `sessionTopics` array.

Comment: Looks like there's some early consensus in favor of the 2nd approach. Also, @apsillers I think you're right, I could lose the "thirdTopic" etc, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a 3rd version, which allows a better iteration of `sessionTopics`

```
var data = {
    "session": {
        "sessionId": "",
        "sessionTitle": "",
        "sessionDescription": "",
        "clientName": "",
        "sessionTopics": [
            {
                "topicName": "name of first topic",
                "topicChoices": [
                    "b", "c", "a", "d", "e", "a", "e", "b", "c", "b"
                ],
                "lmodeRating": 7
            }, {
                "topicName": "second topic name",
                "topicChoices": [
                    "a", "c", "a", "b", "e", "a", "d", "e", "c", "b"
                ],
                "lmodeRating": 9
            }
        ],
        "imageDescriptions": [
            {
                "imageA": "description of image A"
            }, {
                "imageB": "description of image B"
            }, {
                "imageC": "description of image C"
            }, {
                "imageD": "description of image D"
            }, {
                "imageE": "description of image E"
            }
        ],
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd prefer the 2nd one because in this case you can easily figure out individual topic's name, choices and lmodeRating as it is grouped together  and easier to read/understand and maintain.

However I'd also modify it a little bit more. Something like this:

```
"topic": "secondTopic",
"details": {
        "topicName": "second topic name",
        "topicChoices": [
            "a", "c", "a", "b", "e", "a", "d", "e", "c", "b"
        ],
        "lmodeRating": 9
}
```

Note that I've changed individual topic details from array to an object.
Now you can easily access all details without array index.
eg. `session.sessionTopics[0].details.topicName`, instead of `session.sessionTopics[0].firstTopic[0].topicName`

I always prefer to have my keys known beforehand.

Comment: In this case, am I correct in assuming I probably don't really _need_ to have the "topic": "secondTopic" part? In effect, I'd know it's the secondTopic simply by the number in session.sessionTopics[1].details.topicName, right?

Comment: @apsillers Oops, that was a typo, thanks for pointing it out. Fixed it now!

Comment: @ScottM Yes, if you were using it just as identifier and not using it anywhere else.